# Creating latitude, longitude pairs for distance calculation, based on matching zip in 2 spark dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, cartesian-product

I have a pyspark dataframe A, that has 3 columns:

```
Lat lon zip
-69 40  trp
-69 41  nxt
```

I have another pyspark dataframe B, that has same columns, but values captured will be different:

```
Lat lon zip
-68 43  trp
-89 45  trp
```

I want to create latitude longitude pairs for each record of A, based on matching zip in dataframe B.

So the output RDD pairs would be like:

```
(([-69,40],[-68,43]),
 ([-69,40],[-89,45]))
```

Can I do this without looping? I was trying to replicate .map used here:[Spark cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828139/spark-cartesian-product/38831748#38831748)

Unsuccessfully

Answer (score 1):

A cartesian product is a join without any join key, it projects all the lines of a dataframe on all the lines of another dataframe. Say you have 2 dataframes `A` and `B` with `nA` and `nB` rows respectively, then you'll end up with a dataframe with  `nA x nB` rows.

What you are looking for is a regular `inner join` with join key `zip`:

```py
A = spark.createDataFrame([[-69,40,"trp"],[-69,41,"nxt"]], ["Lat","lon","zip"])
B = spark.createDataFrame([[-68,43,"trp"],[-89,45,"trp"]], ["Lat","lon","zip"])
A.join(B, "zip").show()

    +---+---+---+---+---+
    |zip|Lat|lon|Lat|lon|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
    |trp|-69| 40|-68| 43|
    |trp|-69| 40|-89| 45|
    +---+---+---+---+---+
```

**Note:** be carefull with column name disambiguation, you  can for instance put `lon, Lat` in a structure for each dataframe before joining them:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
A = A.select("zip", psf.struct("Lat", "Long").alias("A"))
B = B.select("zip", psf.struct("Lat", "Long").alias("B"))

df = A.join(B, "zip")
df.show()
df.printSchema()

    +---+--------+--------+
    |zip|       A|       B|
    +---+--------+--------+
    |trp|[-69,40]|[-68,43]|
    |trp|[-69,40]|[-89,45]|
    +---+--------+--------+

    root
     |-- zip: string (nullable = true)
     |-- A: struct (nullable = false)
     |    |-- Lat: long (nullable = true)
     |    |-- lon: long (nullable = true)
     |-- B: struct (nullable = false)
     |    |-- Lat: long (nullable = true)
     |    |-- lon: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: ok. Is it suitable to create a dataframe, If each zip say have some 1000 points and I am joining with dataframe that has some 1m points. Or there are alternative ways like RDD or arrays tuples, that take less memory

Comment: You can `broadcast` the small dataframe when joining, this will copy it to everynode to optimize memory usage: `A.join(psf.broadcast(B), "zip")`